# Ajax POST request to Django App with gunicorn as reverse proxy and nginx not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a django view which is being accessed asynchronously by Ajax Requests and works fine when the app is run using the manage.py runserver command and also with gunicorn

But the Ajax requests stop functioning as soon as I shut down the session after running gunicorn.

I have also enabled  the

```
underscores_in_headers on;
```

in the nginx.conf

Also,  here is the error that I have tracked down

```
[Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by shut down the session.

Comment: I meant - closing the terminal window into my remote server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work :

I had a few debug statements inside my views , which when removed got me to get this working . I think the issue was with the screen getting detached post shutting down the terminal.

> gunicorn seems to behave weird with print statements that may have been left unintentionally , its best to avoid them.